# compute partial refresh ID?

Tags: xpages

I would like to compute the ID of a partial refresh target ID. Is this possible?

I am working an a reusable component (custom control) and would like to specify the target ID via the Property Definition instead of hard-coding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

**Code for CustomControl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="#{compositeData.refreshId}">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

**Code for XPage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:label 
        value="#{javascript:java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()}"
        id="label1" />

    <xc:CC refreshId="#{label1}" />

</xp:view>
```

The custom property of the CC is a String named *refreshId*

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<xc:CC refreshId="label1" />`?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth: I think if you just use *label1* it won't work, because then the clientID wouldn't be computed. Interesstingly, I normally would use *#{id:label1}*, but it seems if you bind a component to a String the clientID is automatically derived...

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Makes sense if component's toString implementation returns its clientID. Seems odd. In my opinion you don't need clientID - eventHandler's property refreshID requires server side component's name.